# TypeScript Gatsby project cannot find scss module exports despite custom type declaration

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sass, gatsby

I have a simple Gatsby project that can't find the SCSS module properties that I am trying to import. I'm using **'gatsby-plugin-sass'** version 5.24.0, and Gatsby 4.24.2.

For example, I have a **Footer.tsx** component and a corresponding **Footer.module.scss** file that I use like this:

```
import * as styles from "./css/Footer.module.scss";

const Footer: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.navContainer}>
      <div className="container">
        <div className={styles.navWrapper}>
```

I have a **custom.d.ts** file for the modules like this:

```
declare module "*.scss" {
  const content: Record<string, string>;
  export default content;
}

declare module "*.module.scss" {
  const content: Record<string, string>;
  export default content;
}
```

And my **gatsby-config.js** has these lines to resolve the plugins:

```
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-styled-components`,
    `gatsby-plugin-fontawesome-css-2`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-sass`
    },
```

However, everywhere in VS Code properties like 'navContainer' and 'navWrapper' give errors of "Property 'navWrapper' does not exist on type 'typeof import("*.scss")'.ts(2339)".  My code compiles when I use `// @ts-nocheck` but I'd prefer to understand why this isn't working.

When I change the import declaration to

```
import styles from "./css/Footer.module.scss";
```

As suggested [here](https://github.com/mrmckeb/typescript-plugin-css-modules/issues/16) the errors disappear but my code no longer compiles.  I also tried downgrading the `gatsby-plugin-sass` to version 4.0.0.

I've also reviewed these similar questions, but I've already tried their solutions:

[Cannot import CSS module in .tsx file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53962218/cannot-import-css-module-in-tsx-file)

[Can't import CSS/SCSS modules. TypeScript says "Cannot Find Module"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40382842/cant-import-css-scss-modules-typescript-says-cannot-find-module)

[Gatsby SCSS Module not compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66493108/gatsby-scss-module-not-compiling)

[Typescript type error property does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64716260/typescript-type-error-property-does-not-exist)